# extreme values and saddle points of multivariable function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $f(x,y) = y^3+3xy^2 -6y^2 +2$ .Find the extreme values and the saddle points of $f$ if exist .

My try : I used second derivatives test . The critical points are $(a,0), a\in \mathbb{R}$ . Therefore the value of $D$ is always zero at the critical points and the test is inconclusive. I don't know what is the next step .

Comment: I would try graphing the function to see its behaviour (change in behaviour at $a=2$).

Comment: @Dave This question was in my exam and I couldn't use software .

Comment: Another thing you could do is some numerical testing around the critical points (i.e. for each $(a,0)$ critical point, try plugging in points of the form $(a,b)$ with $b$ close to $0$) to determine how the function looks around each critical point. You can split up into three cases: $a<2$, $a=2$, and $a>2$ since when $a=2$ the Hessian is the zero matrix (so this is a distinguishing point).

Comment: ithink there are no extrem points and no saddle points

Comment: Don’t just go by the determinant of the Hessian; examine the Hessian matrix itself.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner If you look at the graph of function , it seems there are infinite extreme points !

Comment: @amd Can you help about that ? I don't know how to use Hessian matrix .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the critical points are $(a,0)$ with $a \in \mathbb R$, just as you have found. Indeed, the second derivative test is not usable in this problem, so we'll have to study the behaviour of $f$ around the points $(a,0)$ "by hand" (i.e. by improvising).

If $a < 2$, choose $r>0$ such that $4r < 6 - 3a$. Consider the neighbourhood $(a-r,a+r) \times (-r,r)$ of $(a,0)$ and notice that on it

$$y + 3x - 6 < r + 3(a+r) - 6 = 4r + 3a - 6 < 0$$

so that

$$f(x,y) - f(a,0) = y^2(y + 3x - 6) \le y^2 (4r + 3a - 6) \le 0 \ ,$$

which shows that $f(x,y) \le f(a,0)$ on this neighbourhood, so $(a,0)$ is a point of local maximum.

If $a>2$ the analysis is similar: you choose $0 < r < 3a - 6$ and you get that $(a,0)$ is a point of local minimum.

Finally, if $a=2$ then again choose a neighbourhood $(2-r,2+r) \times (-r,r)$ of $(2,0)$ (this time without imposing any restriction on $r>0$) and notice that:

- for $x \in (2-r, 2)$ and $y \in (-r ,0)$ you have $y + 3x - 6 < 0 + 3 \cdot 2 - 6 = 0$, so that $y^2 (y + 3x - 6) <0$;
- for $x \in (2, 2+r)$ and $y \in (0,r)$ you have $y + 3x - 6 > 0 + 3 \cdot 2 - 6 = 0$, so that $y^2 (y + 3x - 6) > 0$.

This shows that on this neighbourhood of $(2,0)$ the difference $f(x,y) - f(2,0)$ takes both negative and positive values, therefore $(2,0)$ is a saddle point.

Comment: Thanks a lot , can you give the exact definition of the saddle point ?

Comment: The definition that I know: it is a critical point that is not a local extremum. Funny, though: *you* are the one expected to provide the definitions, since you give the problem.

Comment: :) Thanks , @amd said that I should examine the Hessian matrix itself . Do you know how I can solve the problem using the Hessian matrix ?

Comment: @S.H.W: I don't know what he meant. When the second derivative test is inconclusive I believe that it is impossible to deduce anything about a point by just "studying" (whatever that means) the Hessian at that point. One may probably deduce a lot about a point by studying the Hessian *in some neighbourhood* of that point - but this is equivalent to what I am doing above.

Comment: @S.H.W: Since you only mention $D$ in your question (I believe that this is the determinant of the Hessian), I believe that **amd** was under the impression that you do not know how to use the second derivative test (which involves more than just the determinant), which does not seem to be the case. It is probably a simple misunderstanding due to the imperfect communication between you two.

Comment: Okay , thanks for your answer .